# How to debug Client side Razor code for Blazor WASM app when it is hosted in a Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly, remote-debugging

I have a simple hosted Blazor WASM app which is running in a Kubernetes Pod.

The app works well with Ingress + TLS for the hosted port (e.g. my-public-hostname:443 -> internal-service-name:5678)

But how can I debug the client side code from my local device if I enable debugging on server side? (e.g. using environment variable `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"`

My debugging Dockerfile is as follows:

```
# Reference: https://docs.tilt.dev/example_csharp.html
# This is used with Tilt's Live Sync feature to sync code changes to a remote container.
# Dotnet watch takes care of recompiling the code when changes are detected.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet:0-7.0

# Install VS Debugger for C# / .NET
# This is needed for VS Code to attach to the running process.
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg

# Install Dotnet Tools

# # This is if you want to use the dotnet-script tool. (e.g. execute csx files)
# RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-script \

#  # This is if you want to use the dotnet-repl tool. (e.g. Interactive C# like ipython)
#  && dotnet tool install --global dotnet-repl \

#  # This is if you want to use the dotnet-interactive tool. (e.g. Jupyter Notebooks)
#  && dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-interactive

# Add "~/.dotnet/tools" to the PATH environment variable.
# This is needed to run the dotnet tools.
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"

# Add .NET Environment variables
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"

# The source code is not copied to the container, but is mounted from the local machine.
# This is done by Tilt's Live Sync feature.
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

# # The dotnet watch command will recompile the code when changes are detected.
# # The entrypoint is also set by Tilt's Live Sync feature.
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--launch-profile=https", "--project=Server", "--no-hot-reload", "--non-interactive", "--verbosity=minimal"]
# ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c", "while true; do sleep 10; done" ]
```

With the above configuration, I have external tools like [Tilt](https://docs.tilt.dev/example_csharp) and [Okteto](https://www.okteto.com/docs/samples/aspnetcore/) that sync my local source code to the Kubernetes Pod's `/app` folder.

I can debug the server side code locally using `kubectl` to ssh via the following `launch.json` config:

```
{
    "name": "Kubectl: .NET Core Kubernetes Attach",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "attach",
    "processName": "/app/Server/bin/Debug/net7.0/my-pwa.Server",
    // "restart": true, // Waiting for: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4822
    "pipeTransport": {
        "debuggerPath": "/root/vsdbg/vsdbg",
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        // This is a workaround for launching kubectl exec with pod name but the script gets the pod name
        "pipeProgram": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/kubectl-launch.sh",
        "quoteArgs": false,
        "justMyCode": false
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/app": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
},
```

Where `kubectl-launch.sh` is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Stop script on error
set -e

# Get Pod name by label selector. app.kubernetes.io/component=webapp and app.kubernetes.io/name=my-pwa
POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace my-pwa --selector app.kubernetes.io/component=webapp,app.kubernetes.io/name=my-pwa -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")

# Use Kubectl to execute command inside the pod as arguments from this file
kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME --namespace my-pwa -- $@
```

But I cannot figure how how to debug client side Web Assembly using VS Code with this setup.

I tried using the below "launch.json" config:

```
{
    "name": "Launch and Debug Standalone Blazor WebAssembly App",
    "type": "blazorwasm",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "dotnet: build",
    "browser": "edge",
    "hosted": false,
},
```

This will initially launch the web browser at `"localhost:5678"` with the server also running locally. But then I cannot figure out how to make the debug instance of the browser open at `"my-public-hostname:443"`

---

**Note:** I need the hosted web app to run in Kubernetes as it has server-side dependencies on other micro-services within the cluster. Those are harder to reproduce locally with Docker-compose as there is also a routing / networking component via service mesh.

**Note:** Here, my definition of debug means setting breakpoints in the IDE (VS Code) and having the IDE stop at that breakpoint to inspect variables, step through the code, etc. Yes, it is possible to do console logging on the WASM client side, which is how I've been debugging so far, but this is becoming very tedious and not sustainable.